# sending data from ajax to spring controller: Required String parameter is not present

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, spring

I know there are already a lot questions about this error message, but nothing helped me to fix my problem.

I'm trying to activate a User account through a table which contains the email, first and last name and a checkbox for each entry.
First you check the checkboxes for which user(s) you want to unlock and then you press a button to send your request, the Controller would then just change the "activated" status from the selected user(s) from 0 for deactivated to 1 for activated.

I have a HTML, a JavaScript and a Java Controller file.
Note that I'm currently trying this on localhost and have turned of google chromes cross origin by launching Chrome per cmd with *chrome.exe --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files*

I want to unlock the user by their email adress in the MainController.java which currently only does a sysout because so far I don't even get to that method because of the error.

I already tried changing the @RequestParam to @RequestBody but it just gives me the error Required request body is missing.

So I quess the main problem is that the email adress I'm getting from the table is not passed on to the Controller, but how do I do that correctly?

what the table looks like:
[screenshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7lVG.png)

the unlock.html

```
<div id="background">
  <div id="scroll-horizontal">
    <form id="table-form" method="POST" action="http://localhost:8080/mitglied/unlockUpdate">
      <table id="table">
        <tr>
          <th>E-Mail</th>
          <th>Vorname</th>
          <th>Nachname</th>
          <th><input id="unlock-all" type="checkbox"></th>
        </tr>
       </table>
       <input id="unlock-btn" type="submit" value="Freischalten"></input>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="../static/js/unlock.js "></script>
```

the JavaScript file unlock.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/mitglied/unlock", function(data) {
        var table_data = "";
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            table_data += "<tr>";
            table_data += "<td>" + value.email + "</td>";
            table_data += "<td>" + value.vorname + "</td>";
            table_data += "<td>" + value.nachname + "</td>";
            table_data += "<td class=" + "unlock-checkbox" + " style=" + "text-align:center" + "><input type=" + "checkbox" + "></input></td>";
            table_data += "</tr>";
        });

        $("#table").append(table_data);
    });

    jQuery('#table-form').submit(function() {
        var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var cols = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            var checkbox = cols[3].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

            if (checkbox.checked) {
                var email = cols[0].innerHTML;

                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr('action'),
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: { email: email },

                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("success, email: " + email);
                        alert("success");
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            }
            console.log(checkbox.checked);
        }
    });
});
```

and the MainController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/mitglied") public class MainController {
@Autowired
  private MitgliederRepository mitgliedRepository;

  @PostMapping(path="/unlockUpdate")
  public @ResponseBody void unlockSelectedUsers(@RequestParam String email) {
      System.out.println(email);
  }
```

the complete error message (on localhost:8080/mitglied/unlockUpdates) is:

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Apr 10 13:43:42 CEST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required String parameter 'email' is not present

Comment: You are passing in JSON from the AJAX request. Change `{ email: email }` to `email` or add an DTO to java side to map the request.

Comment: I tried changing it to just `email` , but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Could you provide the whole error message?

Comment: You also need to change to `@Requestbody`

Comment: I tried that, it just gives a `Required request body is missing`error, which I already got while trying out other things before posting here

Comment: @Lemon Must have and empty body then. Have you checked that `email` is actually set before the ajax call?

Comment: Yes, it is set the `console.log` in the success function does print the correct email. @tmarwen I edited the original post to include the complete error message.

Comment: Looking at the error its clear that requested parameter is not being passed.

Use browser developer tool(by clicking F12) and check the network tab, to be sure that your request is correctly passing the email string as a request parameter.

Comment: @crazy_code for Request Headers it's Content-Length: 0 but how do I fix that it is passed on correctly?

Comment: I would recommend you to use `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam`. Secondly add dataType and contenType to your ajax request. Look at the below example.
var data = {"name":"John Doe"}
$.ajax({
    dataType : "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data : JSON.stringify(data),
    success : function(result) {
        alert(result.success); // result is an object which is created from the returned JSON
    },
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of stuff this is the solution I landed on and works for me

Note that the divs changed and it's no longer a form, the action is now handled via an onclick function. And I already styled it so divs are different now.

the unlock.html

```
<div id="background">
        <div id="frame">
            <h1 id="table-title">Freischaltung</h1>
            <div id="scroll">
                <table id="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>E-Mail</th>
                            <th>Vorname</th>
                            <th>Nachname</th>
                            <th><input id="unlock-all" type="checkbox"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="btn-container">
                <button id="unlock-btn" onclick="submit()">Freischalten</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="../static/js/unlock.js "></script>
```

the JavaScript file unlock.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    updateTable();
});

function updateTable() {
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/mitglied/unlock", function(data) {
        var table_data = "";
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            table_data += "<tr>";
            table_data += "<td>" + value.email + "</td>";
            table_data += "<td>" + value.vorname + "</td>";
            table_data += "<td>" + value.nachname + "</td>";
            table_data += "<td class=" + "unlock-checkbox" + "><input type=" + "checkbox" + "></input></td>";
            table_data += "</tr>";
        });
        $("#table").append(table_data);
    });
}

function submit() {
    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    //get the checked value for each table row
    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var cols = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        var checkbox = cols[3].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

        if (checkbox.checked) {
            var email = cols[0].innerHTML;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/mitglied/unlockUpdate',
                data: { 'email': email },
                success: function(msg) {
                    alert("success");
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and the MainController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/mitglied") public class MainController {
@Autowired
  private MitgliederRepository mitgliedRepository;

  @RequestMapping(path="/unlockUpdate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody void unlockSelectedUsers(@RequestParam (required=false) String email) {
      Iterable<Mitglied> mitglieder = mitgliedRepository.findAll();
      List<Mitglied> mitgliederListe = new ArrayList();
      mitglieder.iterator().forEachRemaining(mitgliederListe::add);

      for (Mitglied m : mitgliederListe) {
          if (m.getEmail().equals(email)) {
              m.setFreigeschaltet(true);
              mitgliedRepository.save(m);
              break;
          }
      }
      System.out.println(email);
  }
```